# Vuetify how to mark field as required

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

When we try to fill forms in the internet, required fields are marked using a red color ' * ' mark to indicate that the field is a must.

Like that is there a way to indicate users to required fields in vuetify.js?

Comment: In my case I used "hint" and "rules" to achieve this for v-text-field and v-textarea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [v1.1.0 docs](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v1.1.0):

> The required prop no longer explicitly adds an asterisk to the label. All of its functionality to validation was removed for v1.0.

So apparently nothing will set it as required anymore, we have to add it manually in the label:

```
label="Name*"
```

---

Or you could use CSS:

```
.required label::after {
    content: "*";
}
```

Tho you must add `required` class manually (name of the class is arbitrary of course).

Comment: I needed to add the css to App.vue

Answer (score 21):

It's a bit of a pain, but there is a 'label' named slot and you can do something like this:

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="loginInfo.email"
  autofocus
  name="email"
  type="email">
    <template #label>
      <span class="red--text"><strong>* </strong></span>Email
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: This solution is 100% Vue/Vuetify and does not rely on styling or CSS which can be problematic or over-ridden. If you set it this way, it will always be there.

Answer (score 4):

You are able to pass a rules prop to a `v-text-field`.

E.g,

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="title"
  :rules="['Required']"
  label="Title"
  counter
  maxlength="20"
></v-text-field>
```

See this Vuetify example for a fuller picture: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/src/examples/text-fields/validation.vue

`required` is also an HTML property. You could just add it to the HTML Element like this:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="title"
  label="Title"
  counter
  maxlength="20"
  required
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: No I mean display a red colored * mark in a text field.

Comment: Your code pen seems not saved. But passing the attribute required to the text field gave me the *  mark. =)

Comment: `required` prop used to mark it as required before `v.1.1.0`. `rules` prop never marked it as far as I know. See my answer for updates with regards to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution, with add this css class into main css file or in main.js.

```
div[aria-required=true].v-input .v-label::after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
```

That's it, in this add field required:

```
<v-text-field required>
```

Comment: not worked for me in vuetify 3

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify 3, I did this :

```css
.v-field:has(input[required]) .v-label {
    padding-inline-end: 8px;
}
.v-field:has(input[required]) .v-label::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    top: 0;
    inset-inline-end: 0; /* to support also RTL direction */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, I don't know if this is the best solution. But it works.

Import the JavaScript file bellow into you application bootstrap (or something like that).

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.mixin({
    mounted() {
        const e = this.$el;

        if ('querySelector' in this.$el) {
            const i = this.$el.querySelector('input[required]');

            if (i !== null) {
                const l = i.previousSibling;

                if (l.querySelector('.required.sign') === null) {
                    const r = document.createElement('span');

                    // l.classList.add('required');
                    r.classList.add('required', 'sign');

                    r.appendChild(document.createTextNode('*'));
                    l.appendChild(r);
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

**Nuxt.js:** put the file above into the `plugins` folder. Include its path on the `plugins` array on the `nuxt.config.js` file.

Add the rule bellow to your global CSS / theme.

```css
.v-label  > .required.sign {
    color: darkred;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: .25em;
}
```