# Vuetify: asterix on required labels

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The latest version of Vuetify (v1.3 - https://libupdate.com/libs/38f99a55-a650-4d67-8e60-cd3c2737d043).

**The asterix is now removed from the label even if the v-textarea/v-text-field has the required prop**. They want you to add it manually in the label prop e.g. label="Message*"

Although in my application there is too many forms to change and was wondering if it can be selected via CSS, although the structure of the HTML is problematic.

```
     <div class="v-text-field__slot">
       <label class="v-label theme--light">Message</label>
       <textarea name="message" required="required" rows="5"></textarea>
     </div>
```

Any help in selecting the label if its before the required input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158705/vuetify-how-to-mark-field-as-required/52935829#52935829

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether this work for you or not with your HTML structure. But this worked for me

```
.required label::after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

Then I normally called this class in my text field.

```
<v-textfield class="required">
```

Comment: Still need to add `required` class manually, so doesn't help (unless the class is there? But I think it's not?). So I think it's not possible to target the label of these elements by not changing anything? Seems like OP wanted to save time by simply targeting `required` inputs, but they will save more time by typing `*` in each field's label, than adding classes to these fields.

Comment: Yes @Traxo, I essentially wish to globally target the labels using CSS without having to amend each place we use an required input. Our inputs could be dynamically set to required, which provides its own problems.