# Vue input required if others are non-empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form collecting an address. A fully specified address is okay, a completely empty one is okay, too, but a partial address is not okay.

I'm trying to express that this way:

```
<v-text-field :required="reqIn(address)" v-model="address.street" label="Street"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field :required="reqIn(address)" v-model="address.city" label="City"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field :required="reqIn(address)" v-model="address.state" label="State"></v-text-field>

// methods
reqIn (address) {
  // addresses may be all blank, or fully specified
  let totalLength = address.street.length + address.city.length + address.state.length + address.zip.length
  console.log(totalLength)
  return totalLength === 0
}
```

I can see the method getting called, and I can see the total length changing as I add and delete chars to the inputs, but when `totalLength` reaches 0, I expect the fields to become styled as required (if they are empty).  But I don't see that happening.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is an extra = here =></v-text-field>

Comment: Thanks @Shim-Sao.  Just a copy paste error.  The form parses.

Comment: Just a heads up that `required` prop has no functionality since v1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935829/1981247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling is done through [vuetify rules](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#usage), and not the `required` directive. For each `v-text-field`, you can use the same rule if you want. Example [code pen](https://codepen.io/philfontaine/pen/BbLrBd).

`required` directive [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the method `reqIn` is called once at the start if you want the value to be dynamic changed whenever a certain variable(s) is updated you can use `computed properties` : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example

Comment: Thanks, but I see the method being called, and I see the total length changing, on every input change.  Also, I think you've got it backwards: the computed property is more apt to be cached and then not called again.