# veutify - How to mark all fields are required by default

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a simple v-form which has few fields in it. I have been trying to mark the fields as required by default, but it is not working as expected. I tried using **Vee-validate** and it has `.initial`, so that it will mark fields are required by default. But the problem here is, it is template based rendering and it is not working well in some cases, if i add a model to the field.

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXLxKr?editors=1010)

In the above example **Validate** button is disabled by default because nothing is filled in the form fields. So here the fields need to show as required, other wise we don't know what to fill in. So how to mark the fields are required by default? is there a option that vuetify is providing or any other package which solves this issue? Thank you.

Update: The fields are actually required, what i mean is, highlighting the fields as Red by default. Display * and all is Needed in my case.

Comment: you could either put `required` on all the fields as I see you did or if you wanted it to be dynamic you could do `:required="someVariable"` dont know of a way to set them up all at once. Also not sure what you mean by "it is not working well in some cases"?

Comment: In the above example i added the Required property right, still it is not working.

Comment: "it is not working well in some cases"- its in Vee-validate package not in vuetify form validation.

Comment: Little confusion all the fields are required means, they all are required but they are not highlighted as red, that what i mean. My intention is to highlight those fields as red.

Comment: have you tried the `error` prop in the api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuetify how to mark field as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158705/vuetify-how-to-mark-field-as-required)

Comment: @Michael i tried and it will work, but why i am not going with :error or :error-messages because they are not exclusively for that specific field. Check the updated Code pen above. See the console, i print 'In error' and 'In required' text. What i am trying to say is the :error property will execute even though we change any other field in the form, but rules are not like that, the rules are specific to that field.

Comment: In the above example there are only 2 fields, but in my component form there are many fields and that method is triggered almost all 10 times, but rules are only once. Do you think this is the preferred way to achieve this?